# Replacing enums with polymorphic classes: how to select types from the UI in WPF / C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, enums, polymorphism

It's understood that using a polymorphic set of subclasses is, in most cases, preferable to using `enum` and `switch`. The part I'm having trouble with is populating a `ListBox` or `ComboBox` with the available types. Binding a listbox to an enum is relatively straight-forward, but how do you do the same thing while avoiding enums altogether?

More specifically, if I have

```
class MyBase
class A : MyBase
class B : MyBase
class C : MyBase
```

How do I make present a listbox on the UI that contains a textual description of each class... something like

```
This is Class A
This is Class B
This is Class C
```

*and* have an instance of class `B` created after the user selects the 2nd item in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get types that inherits from `MyBase`:

```
var baseType =  typeof(MyBase);
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(x));
```

Then the rest is easy, for example you can have a list of key value pairs where `Key` is the class type and the `Value` is the description of the type, and set the `ValueMember` to `Key`, `DisplayMember` to `Value`:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => typeof(MyBase).IsAssignableFrom(x));
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(x,"This is " + x.Name))
        .ToList();
```

Then handle the `SelectedChanged` event, and get the `SelectedValue`, cast it to `Type`, use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance.

Comment: If you go this route you may want to put this code in a static method of the base class and cache the results there for future calls.  Enumerating all the types declared in an assembly isn't something you want to do often.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the ToString method of the class instance.
Your listbox should display the ToString result.

So set the ItemsSource of your ListBox to an ObservableCollection of your class instances and rely on the ToString to display the value in the listBox.

Comment: but the OP doesnt have a list of instance of those clasess. he wants all classes that derives from MyBase. and create an instance of the Selected type. Have you read the question?

Comment: He does. He's relying on the Stratagy Pattern. So he has a base class or interface that his code is pointing to but a specific implementation to get executed. Did you read his question?

Comment: "How do I make present a listbox on the UI that contains a textual description of each class... " see, he says _class_, not _instance_. and wants to create an instance of  selected type`. if he already has the instances, why would he want to create a new instance of selected type? your answer assumes he does have instances, but there is no evidence that he does, except your claiming...